# Parse file with two columns into dictionary using C#

Tags: c#, parsing, dictionary, split

I am new in C#, and needs to help! 
How to parse file like:

```
0.05;32.302758269034
0.050001;32.3019279599779
```

to dictionary? What libraries are necessary?

Thancks a lot!

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Break your problem in to smaller parts and you might be able to figure it on your own, try to solve these problems one by one. 1)Read a file line by line and process it one line at a time. 2)Split a single line of data in to a class that hold two items of data split on a `;` (doesn't have to be a custom class, it could just be going from a `string` to a `string[2]`). 3)Convert a list of a class containing two data objects in to a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You will need [System.IO.File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb549277%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).